# Given two non-commuting matrices, can we always find another nontrivial matrix that commute with each of them?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given two non-commuting matrices $A,B$, can we always find another nontrivial matrix $C$ that commute with each of them and how to construct $C$ explicitly?

This is sort of the converse statement of that fact that commutation relation are not transitive. If the statement is not generally true, what minimal constraints could be added such that it is true?

Comment: What about the identity matrix?

Comment: well, let's say other than the identity @lulu

Comment: The zero matrix?

Comment: Any scalar multiple of the identity then.  I think you may want to refine your question.

Comment: Have you tried making examples with $2\times2$ matrices, for instance?

Comment: Speaking loosely, for a generic matrix (distinct eigenvalues, say) the centralizer just consists of polynomials in the matrix itself.  It should follow that for two, generic, non-commuting matrices  (no common invariant subspace, say) the common centralizer just consists of scalars.

Comment: [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201916/finding-commuting-matrices) is a relevant discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the matrices $$A=\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}, B=\pmatrix{1&0\\1&1}$$ it's easy to check that only the scalar matrices commute with both $A$ and $B$.  Indeed those that commute with $A$ are of the form $$\pmatrix{a&b\\0&a},$$ and those that commute with $B$ are of the form $$\pmatrix{a&0\\c&a}$$